# What measurements can I take to prevent an ubuntu update from rendering my laptop useless?

Tags: updates, data-recovery

Today is the second time my laptop has not been functional all day after performing a system update. The problem has still not been fixed, but I don't want to focus on this particular problem, as some years back my desktop also suffered from a system breaking update, and another laptop lost wireless internet because of one.

My question is, what are some things I can do to recover from a malicious update as soon as possible? I simply cannot afford hunting some mysterious bug all day, all I want is for things to be the way they were before the update.

Ubuntu does not have any "system recovery" concept like Windows does, as far as I know, but something like this is what I would like to mimic. I know you can revert individual packages to a previous version, but this is said to not be the same as the pre-update package. It also requires going through potentially many packages.

For what it's worth, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the default update settings, no experimental packages or anything.

To get a better idea of what I'm looking for, here are some ideas that came up after some brainstorming:

- Somehow create a snapshot of the state of the OS before updating, similar to the ones you use with a virtual machine. Then be able to revert to that snapshot. No clue if this is feasible.
- Create a script to automatically fetch the updated packages of the last update, then revert all of them automatically.
- Install two Ubuntu's on the machine, create back-ups best as possible and in case of failure of the main Ubuntu, switch to back-up. The draw-back is having to install/configure software twice, there's quite some overhead.

I'm quite frustrated as this is taking up entirely too much time, please help me prevent 
this situation in the future.

Comment: I just double checked it, the only ones enabled are "trusty-security" and "trusty-updates", important security updates and recommended updates.

Comment: Ok. Are you willing to reinstall Ubuntu for now?

Comment: I'm not quite at that point yet, there are still some things I want to try. If I haven't fixed it in a few hours that will be the course of action, yes.

Comment: I ask because snapshotting can be done using either LVM or a root partition formatted btrfs. Both would require reinstallation. (Well, ext4 can be converted to btrfs, but still...)

Comment: Is this not what back up software is for ?

Comment: @muru I just had a look at [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) and it definitely seems like it could be what I'm looking for. Will check it out in more detail later. at mark kirby As far as I'm aware the backup software only backs up files. If an update renders my OS practically useless, the only course of action would be to reinstall and restore files from the back up, not something that is quick to do. FWIW, I fixed the problem without a reinstall, turns out the [nvidia drivers](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1360024) were at fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used lvm. It sounds really great. Barring something like that or a filesystem like xfs or maybe btrfs, try the following.

Bear in mind that my experience is with desktop systems and things involving servers may be a bit different.

It ain't pretty, but you can always boot a live CD and use a tool like partimage, dump, or even tar or rsync to copy your entire root and home partitions to another partition, preferably on another drive, but you have to do this *before* you run your updates or anything else breaks.

Note the use of a live CD (or another Linux running from another partition, etc.) because root and, very often, home get updated all the time on a live system and you want a copy of all the files frozen at the same moment in time so they all agree with each other.

This can be optimized a bit if you know of things that don't change or don't matter and exclude them from the backups - things like caches, /tmp (in most cases), and, especially, .thumbnails. (And if you're going file by file - like with rsync or tar, skip /sys and /proc because they aren't "real" filesystems anyway. In most cases, you can also skip lost+found on each partition. On /home, most of what matters in this case are config files - usually in hidden directory trees which start with $HOME/.rest of path  (The . makes the directories invisible to most commands and programs unless you tell them to look for files/directories like that.)

Since most updates won't scramble your system, you don't need a full backup like this before every one of them. Just make sure your backup is recent enough to be functional and that your current data files are either on their own partition - safely out of the way - or much more fully backed up.

If you go the full backup route, there are tools like rsync and things built on top of it which use hard links to make subsequent full backups based on an original backup, but which essentially only take up additional space for files that have actually changed content since the original or last backup.

As alluded to above, it's almost always a good idea to store /home on its own separate partition. That mostly insulates it from upgrade issues like having to restore / from a backup. Only the configuration files and any file format or new content changes have to be dealt with. (Programs like Firefox and Thunderbird seem to change almost all their files very frequently.)

I don't see anybody else talking about it, but I partition a new system with two roots and two homes (pairs of live and backup, around 30GB each), swap, and whatever is left goes into a big data partition - which is almost immune to update issues and can be fully backed up and restored at any time on my live system as long as I stop any applications that might be writing to it.

If you make backups this way, you can (almost) just switch to the backups (in your boot menu, e.g. grub) and start running again without doing anything else. (You do have to point the fstab entry for /home in your backup root partition to the partition where the backup of /home is.)

This also gives you the option of switching to your backup immediately so you can continue getting work done - possibly with the option of keeping the broken versions around to see if you can diagnose or fix them when time permits.