# What will happen to all my tools if I upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04LTS?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

### What will happen to all my tools ?

Currently I have been using Ubuntu 20.04LTS in my system for 2 years. I am a MERN stack Developer and my system has so many developer tools like **node.js, mongodb, npm, postgres, mysql** and some other tools also. And all my projects are using these tools and their versions.
So What is going to happen if I upgrade my OS to 22.04LTS will it also update all my tools to fit the new OS environment or if it will just update OS and don’t touch any other tools than did all tools will work as they were working before.
I wanted to know the precautions and concerns that I need to remember before updating to the new LTS version.
Please answer these questions as we need to update our system from time to time.

> I was searching all these questions and googled a lot and found
> that some users suffered after updating their OS.
> [John Kimani](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73737933/14886384), [Bas](https://askubuntu.com/q/515901/1626690)

Comment: "*found that some users suffered after updating their OS*" Sure, that usually happens when folks expect all the non-Ubuntu applications that they installed to magically be compatible with the newer release of Ubuntu. that might be you, too...or not. Insufficient data.

Answer (score 1):

All tools from the default Ubuntu repositories that were installed by apt will be automatically upgraded when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.

All tools that were **not** installed from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 will **not** be upgraded automatically.

Comment: Thank You so much for sharing kind information. Thanks.